# Error con tipo de dato en Python

Tags: python, variables

quiero preguntar porqué en Python cuando ejecuto el siguiente código en Visual Studio Code, me indica que es un entero cuando debería ser un string:

Archivo.py

```
variable = 20190101_11031
print(type(variable))
```

Resultado:

```
<class 'int'>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no entiendo porqué me sale ese tipo de dato si claramente no es entero, o si?.

Comment: Python interpreta ese valor como entero, no importa si agregaste un guion bajo.
Para que sea `string` te falta encerrar entre comillas el valor de la variable, sería: `variable = '20190101_11031'`

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [PEP 515](https://peps.python.org/pep-0515/).

Comment: La verdadera pregunta es: ¿por qué crees que no es un entero y si un string? No tiene comillas así que no puede ser un string.

Comment: Gracias a todos por la respuesta, efectivamente comprendí que por legibilidad de números de muchas cifras se puede añadir el guión bajo para esto...

Supuse que el guión bajo era un caracter y por eso toda la variable debía ser string, pero me queda ya claro el porqué no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La [documentación de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) especifica tres formas de definir un string:

> - Comillas simples: `'permite incluir comillas "dobles"'`
> - Comillas dobles: `"permite incluir comillas 'simples'"`
> - Triples comillas: ya sea con comillas simples `'''Triples comillas simples'''` o dobles `"""Triples comillas dobles"""`

Tú no estás usando ninguno de estos tres métodos así que no estás definiendo un string.

Si te sorprende que puedas escribir una barra baja en un número, es una posibilidad que se añadió en Python 3.6 ([PEP 515](https://peps.python.org/pep-0515/)) para la legibilidad de números de muchas cifras.
Como se especifica en el PEP, sólo se permite una única barra baja consecutiva.
Así que:

```py
1_000_000 # Correcto
1__000___000 # SyntaxError
```

Según la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals):

> Los guiones bajos se ignoran para determinar el valor numérico del literal.
> Se pueden utilizar para agrupar los dígitos para mejorar la legibilidad.
> Un guión bajo puede ocurrir entre dígitos y después de especificadores de base como `0x`.

Comment: gracias Jorge Luis por la aclaración, comprendido.